# Segmentation fault when using Xlsxwriter and PyQt4

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyqt, pyqt4, xlsxwriter

I"m currently getting a segmentation fault when using Python modules Xlsxwriter and PyQt4 in the same script. Simply importing PyQt4 while running Xlsxwriter results in the segmentation fault.

```
import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def WriteExcel(guitext,filename):
    import xlsxwriter
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Test Tab') 
    worksheet.write(0, 0, guitext) 
    workbook.close() 
    return


def main():
    WriteExcel('test text', 'test.xlsx')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Commenting out the "from PyQt4 import QtGui" fixes the issue, although I need to use the Gui to get the information to send to the Excel file. Any ideas on a work around? I've tried similar code with openpyxl instead of xlsxwriter and I still get a seg. fault.

The seg. fault results from gdb is below.

```
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from [path to]/anaconda/bin/python...done.
Starting program: [path to]/anaconda/bin/python qtgui-excel.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaab0541624 in fill_window () from [path to]/anaconda/lib/libz.so.1
```

Maybe it has something to do with writing XML?

**Update:**

Tracked down the error to the compression used in the ZipFile command in Xlsxwriter.

```
zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
```

This compression uses the libz module according to the Zipfile documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe it has something to do with writing XML

Probably not. XlsxWriter uses it's own xml writer.

The segfault seems to be in `libz` which is called from the core zipfile module which is used by both XlsxWriter and OpenPyXL.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a common method of dealing with this kind of conflict?

Comment: It is probably best to try isolate the issue down a bit more. Try a simple ZipFile write example [like the one in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) and see if that segfaults. If it does then report this as an issue to the PyQT4 devs. If not then it make take a bit more digging to see what feature of the ZipFile module that XlsxWriter/OpenPyXL is using that causes this.

Comment: Although the first step should probably be to run the XlsxWriter part of the program without PyQt4 and see if you get the segfault. If you do then it isn't a PyQt4 issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've narrowed down the code that breaks PyQt4.


`import sys `
`from PyQt4 import QtGui` 
`def WriteZip():` 
`   import zipfile` 
`   zf = zipfile.ZipFile('zipfile_write.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)`  
`   zf.write('README.txt')`
`   zf.close()`  
`   return`  
`def main():`  
`   WriteZip()`  
`if __name__ == '__main__':`  
`   main()   `  
This breaks at the zf.write command. But ONLY if the commpression is set to 
`    compression=zip.ZIP_DEFLATED` 

The zipfile module even says that ZIP_DEFLATED requires zlib.